# Checking URL validity with jQuery doesn't work except for localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I'm trying to check if a specific ASMX Web service exists by using the `ajax` method of jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/MyApp/MyWebService.asmx',
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            });
```

It works well (`success` event) with localhost (`http://localhost/MyApp/MyWebService.asmx`) but not (`error` event) with my computer name (`http://MyComputerName/MyApp/MyWebService.asmx`) whereas I can call it from my web browser. It doesn't work either when I try to call the same Web service which is also on another server accessible through the Internet (`http://www.example.com/MyApp/MyWebService.asmx`).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: Or is there any other way to check if a URL can be accessed with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs...

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This is not a JSONP request nor a script. It's just a call to check if the file exists. Why wouldn't it work even when adding the property `crossDomain`? Is there anything else I can do to check if a file exists? Thanks!